# How to change log directory location in postgresql 9.4?

Tags: database, postgresql, logging

my current log_directory path is

```
**/opt/demo/PostgreSQL/9.4/data/pg_log**
```

I'm trying to change the log directory path to

```
**/logs/demo/**
```

The server won't start when i uncomment the log path and it starts only when its default.

The **postgresql.conf** file looks like

```
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'         # Valid values are combinations of
                                  # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on
# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
#log_directory = '/logs/etbos/demo/'  #directorywherelogfiles are written
#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'  # log file name pattern,


# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'
```

Comment: Please add error logs, probably postgres user does not have sufficient privileges to acces new log directory.

Comment: This is after i changed the log path                                                              2016-03-09 16:41:43 EST FATAL:  could not open log file "/logs/demo/postgresql-2016-03-09_164143.log": Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what I supposed :) You need to grant permissions to the new log directory to postgres user.

You can do this using f.e.:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /your/new/log/dir/path
```

*Answering your other question:*

To allow TCP/IP connections from remote hosts you need to edit `pg_hba.conf` file.
You can allow **ALL** TCP/IP connections by adding a line like this:

```
host  all  all   0.0.0.0/32  md5
```

There are five parameters above, you can read about them in the pg_hba.conf file in the comments at the top of the file, but in short they mean:

```
[connection_type] [database_name] [user_name] [remote_ip/mask] [auth_type]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please tell How to enable tcp/ip connections to connect from pgadmin to the server?  Please bear with me i'm a beginner.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdabrowski. Made my job a lot easier.  Should it be 0.0.0.0/32 or 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, if you want to allow everything you can use `0` at the end :)

Comment: Thank you but even after i made changes in the pg_hba.conf.. Im still not able to connect to the database using pgadmin.  It still says connection refused

Comment: Maybe you're using wrong port to connect? The default is `5432`, but maybe you've changed it in postgresql.conf file?

Comment: Also in postgresql.conf file you need to set `listen_addresses = '*'`.

Comment: You have to check the connection then, make sure so firewall blocks it, etc.

Comment: Yes, the firewall's blocking it. Thanks a lot.