# where are docker's volumes taken from while we dockerize an app

Tags: postgresql, docker

Let's take postgres for instance. In the [dockerize postgres](https://docs.docker.com/samples/postgresql_service/) page, they've mentioned we can dockerize postgres ourselves if we need it.

In it, there's a volume section that lists this:

```
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

My question is, since these paths are pre-specified, i.e. we've not done anything to configure this so that postgres knows to write to these, when we later create a named volume using docker we're gonna have to specify this location via `$> ... -v <name>:<one_of_above_location>` and not just some arbitrary location:

1. Does the path in the `-v <name>:<location>` have to match the one of
   the locations specified in `VOLUME` section of the Dockerfile?(I've
   only verified this experimentally, so I don't really know).
2. How do they know this is the location to where specific things are
   expected to be written by postgres?
3. How do we change them in our containerized version of docker? i.e.
   be able to  put different paths in the VOLUMES section of the
   Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to explain the Docker part of this question (mainly part 1).

1. No, if the container path doesn't match Docker will create a new mount point for you
2. That is likely specified in your configuration file, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35903046/4676641)
3. See 2 and [relevant docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-logging.html)

When written in the Dockerfile, the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) instruction creates a mount point where you can optionally use a bind mount (when you use the `-v` flag) and have your local filesystem store the data in the container's `/etc/postgresql` or `/var/log/postgresql`. If you don't specify a local bind-mount, Docker will create and manage the volume for you in the "Docker filesystem". Here are [more details about the mount types](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#more-details-about-mount-types).

As an important note, you don't need a `VOLUME` section in the Dockerfile to use a bind mount. If you run the contianer with `-v <path-or-docker-volume-name>:<container-path>`, Docker will create the mount point at `<container-path>` automatically.

And if you don't run the container with any specified mounts for these volumes, you'll end up with anonymous Docker managed volumes which are mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66131461/4676641)

Comment: the configuration files are supposed to be inside the container, right? But, I can't find the postgresql.conf file in the /etc/ directory as hinted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903046/how-to-change-log-directory-location-in-postgresql-9-4

Comment: The tutorial you linked has `RUN` commands in its Dockerfile that create a `postgres.conf` file so it's created at build-time. So could add more `RUN echo <content> > /path/to/postgres.conf` lines or `COPY` a local file as well.

Comment: it being created dynamically doesn't mean that it should be deleted right? Why is it not present in the filesystem?

Comment: @juztcode It's up to you whether you want to delete them, you don't have to. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66132815/4676641) if you want to find them, to delete them you can run `docker volume rm <HASH>` or `docker volume prune`. They're present in your Docker managed filesystem not your local filesystem since you never told Docker where to "put" those files locally.

Comment: I was actually talking about locating the postgres.conf file, did you mean the configuration files was supposed to be in one of the volumes?

Comment: @juztcode Ah. yes. It *should* be in one of the volumes since you mount the path `/etc/postgresql` and the conf file should be at `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`
Depending on how you mount it, it might not be easily accessable though.